# Is there any possible way to have an if statement in MessageBox.Show()

Tags: c#, winforms

Heres my code:

```
MessageBox.Show("numberOfTransactions: " 
                + transactionLabel.Text 
                + Environment.NewLine 
                + Environment.NewLine 
                + if(numberHpLaptops > 0)
                  {
                    "The number of laptops that you have bought is: " 
                        + numberHpLaptops};
```

Comment: Yes, using a StringBuilder...

Comment: `if` isn't a function, and has no return value, so you can't do `blah + if() + blah`.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti StringBuilder is overheaded for constant numbers of arguments (substings).

Comment: @VadimMartynov overheaded? You won't notice any performance improvement (even if it's faster and it doesn't allocate multiple intermediate results) but advantage is to make **code readable**. Check Vadim's answer and you'll see what I mean. Note that there you'll use AppendFormat() and AppendLine() instead of plain Append() and it supports a fluent syntax - in case a one-line code lover wants to do so.

Answer (score 7):

It has nothing to do with `MessageBox.Show`.  Essentially in this operation you're just building a string:

```
"some string" + "another string" + "a third string"
```

If you want to conditionally include a string as part of this, you can use [the ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).  Something like this:

```
"some string" + (someCondition ? "another string" : "") + "a third string"
```

This basically means "if some condition is true, result in the first option, else, result in the second option".  As long as the entirety of the operator (enclosed in parentheses here for clarity) atomically results in the correct type, it can be used in-line in any such operation.

---

Note: There are also other ways to do this.  As mentioned in a comment on the question, a `StringBuilder` can be very useful.  For example:

```
var myString = new StringBuilder();
myString.Append("some string");
if (someCondition)
    myString.Append("another string");
myString.Append("a third string");

MessageBox.Show(myString.ToString());
```

The performance is slightly different between the two, if that matters in your case.  The readability is very different, though.  And while subjective that sort of thing can be very important as the complexity of the code changes.

If performance is an issue you can also use `string.Format()` and create a single formatted string, using in-line conditionals as above to add the strings (or empty strings) as needed.  This would *probably* be the most performant option.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about Immediate If's!

Comment: StringBuilder is overheaded for constant numbers of arguments (substings) and can be worst solution in this situation.

Comment: @VadimMartynov: Possibly, but that also comes down to the needs of performance vs. readability in this system.  Sometimes it makes a lot of sense to do something that's a little slower if the code is much easier to support.  (Business critical systems with few concurrent users, for example.)

Comment: @VadimMartynov also note that using multiple "+" you will create multiple intermediate results. As already said...not such a pity but no gain to do it. Also String.Format() - see Ted's answer or string interpolation in dasblinkenlight's answer - does like this.

Answer (score 4):

```
MessageBox.Show("numberOfTransactions: " 
            + transactionLabel.Text 
            + Environment.NewLine 
            + Environment.NewLine 
            + (numberHpLaptops > 0 
                     ? ("The number of laptops that you have bought is: " + numberHpLaptops) 
                     : string.Empty));
```

In [C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) you can also use [String interpolation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#string-interpolation):

```
MessageBox.Show($"numberOfTransactions: {transactionLabel.Text}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}{numberHpLaptops > 0 ? "The number of laptops that you have bought is: " + numberHpLaptops : string.Empty}");
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.Format` can help to increase readability and testability:

```
string laptopsMsg = "";
if(numberHpLaptops > 0)
    laptopsMsg = "The number of laptops that you have bought is: " + numberHpLaptops.ToString();

string msg = String.Format("numberOfTransactions: {0}{1}{1}{2}"
    , transactionLabel.Text
    , Environment.NewLine
    , laptopsMsg);
MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

You could use the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx) instead. But i prefer the approach above.

Comment: This is how I would've answered it, but the other answers have identified a pretty neat way of making "if" statements redundant.

Comment: Thanks, Im only in my 2nd month of c# so I dont know alot but this helped alot!

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use string interpolation with a conditional expression to put the extra text into the message, it is better to prepare the message outside the call to `MessageBox.Show`:

```
var message = $"numberOfTransactions: {transactionLabel.Text}";
if (numberHpLaptops > 0) {
    message += $"{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}The number of laptops that you have bought is: {numberHpLaptops}";
}
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
MessageBox.Show( string.Format("numberOfTransactions: {0}{1}{1}{2}",
    transactionLabel.Text , Environment.NewLine, (numberHpLaptops > 0) 
        ? string.Format("The number of laptops that you have bought is: {0}", numberHpLaptops)
        : string.Empty));
```